# Convert a string to hex

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to convert a string to hex code.I am using
 xamarin.The only output I get is {0:X}

```
string a = "msg";    
char[] val = a.ToCharArray();

foreach (char c in val)    
{    
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(val);    
    string z = Java.Lang.String.Format("{0:X}",b);    
    outEditText.Text = z;    
}
```

Comment: You want to use the .NET String.Format (System.String.Format), not the Java String.Format

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one line solution using linq:

```
var msg = "msg";
msg.Select(i => ((int)i).ToString("X")).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work for you.
You don't need to convert to a character array and you're using the wrong string formatter.

```
string a = "msg";  

foreach (char c in a)    
{       
    int val = Convert.ToInt32(c);
    string z = String.Format("{0:X}",val); 
    Console.WriteLine(z);  
}
```